# Arrange array of objects based on the condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, conditional-statements

```js
const notificdations = [
  {
    to: "13101",
    senderId: "13279",
    senderFullName: "Md Taaj Uddin",
    type: "ON_BREAK",
    message: "Md Taaj Uddin was on break since last 2 minutes.",
    createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:12:00.068Z",
    status: "read",
  },
  {
    to: "13101",
    senderId: "13267",
    senderFullName: "Md Taaj Uddin",
    type: "IDLE",
    message: "Md Taaj Uddin is idle since last 18 minutes.",
    createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:29:56.623Z",
    status: "read",
  },
  {
    to: "13101",
    senderId: "13213",
    senderFullName: "Gaurav Rajput",
    type: "ON_BREAK",
    message: "Gaurav Rajput was on break since last 5 minutes.",
    createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:32:00.068Z",
    status: "read",
  },
  {
    to: "13101",
    senderId: "13214",
    senderFullName: "Saurav Rajput",
    type: "ON_BREAK",
    message: "Saurav Rajput was on break since last 5 minutes.",
    createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:35:00.068Z",
    status: "read",
  },
  {
    to: "13101",
    senderId: "13266",
    senderFullName: "Rohan",
    type: "IDLE",
    message: "Rohan is idle since last 18 minutes.",
    createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:40:56.623Z",
    status: "read",
  }
];
```

I am wondering how to arrange the array of objects in above case . I want above array of objects arrange according to  type wise means same type come together  and in type ascending according to createdAt key.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: use an Object to define the type as keys and store the relative data in an array.

```js
const arrangedNotifications = {
  IDLE: [
    {
      to: "13101",
      senderId: "13267",
      senderFullName: "Md Taaj Uddin",
      message: "Md Taaj Uddin is idle since last 18 minutes.",
      createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:29:56.623Z",
      status: "read",
    },
    {
      to: "13101",
      senderId: "13266",
      senderFullName: "Rohan",
      message: "Rohan is idle since last 18 minutes.",
      createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:40:56.623Z",
      status: "read",
    },
  ],
  ON_BREAK: [
    {
      to: "13101",
      senderId: "13279",
      senderFullName: "Md Taaj Uddin",
      message: "Md Taaj Uddin was on break since last 2 minutes.",
      createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:12:00.068Z",
      status: "read",
    },

    {
      to: "13101",
      senderId: "13213",
      senderFullName: "Gaurav Rajput",
      message: "Gaurav Rajput was on break since last 5 minutes.",
      createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:32:00.068Z",
      status: "read",
    },
    {
      to: "13101",
      senderId: "13214",
      senderFullName: "Saurav Rajput",
      message: "Saurav Rajput was on break since last 5 minutes.",
      createdAt: "2021-08-20T10:35:00.068Z",
      status: "read",
    },
  ],
};
```